# How to estimate poses by tensorflow posenet

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've downloaded the tflite model from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/pose_estimation/overview and I want to use it to estimate poses in images on my laptop with python, how to load the model and use it to do this?